# best way to map a string to its corresponding value

Tags: java

I would like to write a method that map the input string to its coresponding value, ex: when I input separator = "Semicolon", then I would like to return its value as ';'. What I am doing right now is using switch case:

```
    switch (separator) {
        case "Semicolon":
            return ';';
        case "Comma":
            return ',';
        default:
            return '-';
        }
```

I just would like to ask that beside using switch case here, are there any other solutions that having the same effect but might be shorter line of code. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: `Map` (like e.g. `HashMap`)? as the name suggest used for mapping... but this is very opinion based...

Comment: Why not use an actual `Map` such as a `HashMap<String, Character>`?

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept! Happy mapping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simply answer lies in your wording: **mapping**. As in:

```
Map<String, Character> operatorsByName = new HashMap<>();
operatorsByName.put("Comma", ',');
```

and so on. Or with Java9, the nice new [of()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-collections-factory-methods) method to create maps from "literals".

And then you can just `get()` based on incoming strings. Alternatively, *enum*, and *EnumSet* could come in handy.

Comment: maybe also a case for `Map.of()`...(not that relevant, I know)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger True, added that part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to maintain the mapping dynamically.

```
Map<String, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Semicolon", ';');
map.put("Comma", ',');
return map.getOrDefault(separator, '-');
```

or you can use [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V)) factory method:

```
Map<String, Character> map = Map.of("Semicolon", ';', "Comma", ',');
return map.getOrDefault(separator, '-');
```

Comment: here too, a case for `Map.of()`?!

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger sure, but it depends on the Java version. Added this to the answer.

Comment: sure, but same is (was a long time ago) true for `HashMap` [:-P

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant way would be to use an enum instead:

```
public enum Separator {
   COMMA(","),
   SEMICOLON(";");

 private String symbol;

 Separator(String code) {
   this.symbol = code;
 } 

 public String symbol() {
    return this.symbol;
 }


}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
 String comma = Separator.COMMA.symbol();
```

and as suggested one can also use:

```
Separator.valueOf("COMMA").symbol()
```

Maybe in this way, you don't need any switch / case at all. 
I can imagine that you could pass the "right" Separator that is needed.

Comment: That is a convenient way to "list" the available symbols, but it lacks the ability to map them to an incoming String value.

Comment: You could look up the value e.g. with Grammar.valueOf("COMMA").symbol()